# Proving that $U(f, P_1) + U(f, P_1) = U(f, P\cup c)$ where $P_1 + P_2 = P\cup c$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < c < b$. Let P be an arbitrary partition of [a,b]. Also, let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be partitions of [a,c] and [c,b] respectively, such that $P_1 + P_2 = P\cup c$. I'm trying to show that $U(f,P \cup \{c\})$ equals $U(f,P_1) + U(f,P_2)$. Here's what I have currently, but I feel like there is some justification missing going from the first to last step to the last step:

Let $n$, $n_1$, and $n_2$ be the number of partitions in $P$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively. Note that $n = n_1+n_2-1$
$$U(f,P_1) + U(f,P_2)$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^{n_1}sup\{f([t_{k-1}, t_k])\}(t_k-t_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=n_1+1}^{n_1+n_2}sup\{f([t_{k-1}, t_k])\}(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
$$=sup\{f([a, t_1])\}(t_1-a) + sup\{f([t_1, t_2])\}(t_2-t_1) + ...+ sup\{f([t_{n_1 - 1}, t_{n_1}])\}(t_{n_1}-t_{n_1 - 1}) + sup\{f([t_{n_1}, t_{n_1 + 1}])\}(t_{n_1 + 1}-t_{n_1}) + ... + sup\{f([t_{n_1 + n_2 - 1}, t_{n_1 + n_2}])\}(t_{n_1 +n_2}-t_{n_1 + n_2 - 1})$$
$$=sup\{f([a, t_1])\}(t_1-a) + sup\{f([t_1, t_2])\}(t_2-t_1) + ...+ sup\{f([t_{n_1 - 1}, c])\}(c-t_{n_1 - 1}) + sup\{f([c, t_{n_1 + 1}])\}(t_{n_1 + 1}-c) + ... + sup\{f([t_{n}, t_{n+1}])\}(t_{n+1}-t_{n})$$
$$=U(f,P\cup c) $$

Comment: Why are $P_1$ and $P_2$ arbitrary partitions of $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, respectively?

Comment: @SenZen Whoops that was a mistake I'll change it